# Set Sticky Header and Items Layouts Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, stickyrecycleview

I want to build a complex layout using recyclerview android. In the layout, I want to have a camera button to the top left fixed and a recyclerview wrapped around it with gallery images. I have checked `flexbox layout manager for recyclerview` but it doesn't seem to match my use-case.

I want the header to be non-repeating and not to scroll with other items vertically. Here's the layout for the header:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/shareLayout"
android:layout_width="185dp"
android:layout_height="135dp"
android:layout_below="@id/trendingToolbar"
android:background="@color/black">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cameraShareIV"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/camera_white" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/cameraShareIV"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/share_pic_video"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/infoTxt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="@string/share_timeout_txt"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in my activity, here's the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="base.android.com.thumbsapp.UI.Fragments.TrendingFragment">

<include layout="@layout/trending_toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/trendingToolbar"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/trendingRV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/trendingToolbar"/>
```

Previously, I had the header inside the activity XML but had no way to wrap a recyclerview around it. So, I have decide to use an adapter like below:

```
public class TrendingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = TrendingAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private Context context;
private List<Trending> itemList;

private static final int HEADER = 0;
private static final int ITEMS = 1;

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    switch (viewType){
        case HEADER:
           v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.trending_header, parent, false);
           return new TrendingHeaderViewHolder(v);
        case ITEMS:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.trending_items_layout, parent, false);
            return new TrendingItemsViewHolder(v);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Trending tr = itemList.get(position);
    if (holder instanceof TrendingHeaderViewHolder){
        ((TrendingHeaderViewHolder) holder).cameraShareIV.setOnClickListener( view -> {
            // TODO: 4/2/2018   select image from gallery
        });
    } else if (holder instanceof TrendingItemsViewHolder){
        // TODO: 4/2/2018 populate gallery items here with picasso  
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
}
```

I'm confused how to make the header stick and also what to do for `getItemViewType method`.

Is this the right way to approach this?
Can anyone help out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make things simple i suggest you to look into [this](https://github.com/TellH/RecyclerStickyHeaderView) library

In your XML Place RecylerView into `StickyHeaderView`,choose horizontal or vertical orientation for your `RecylerView`

```
 <tellh.com.stickyheaderview_rv.StickyHeaderView
        android:id="@+id/stickyHeaderView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </tellh.com.stickyheaderview_rv.StickyHeaderView>
```

Create data bean class for each item type in RecyclerView. They should extend `DataBean`. Override the method 
`public boolean shouldSticky()` to decide whether the item view should be suspended on the top.

```
public class User extends DataBean {
    private String login;
    private int id;
    private String avatar_url;
    private boolean shouldSticky;
    @Override
    public int getItemLayoutId(StickyHeaderViewAdapter adapter) {
        return R.layout.item_user;
    }
    public void setShouldSticky(boolean shouldSticky) {
        this.shouldSticky = shouldSticky;
    }
    // Decide whether the item view should be suspended on the top.
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSticky() {
        return shouldSticky;
    }
}
public class ItemHeader extends DataBean {
    private String prefix;
    @Override
    public int getItemLayoutId(StickyHeaderViewAdapter adapter) {
        return R.layout.header;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSticky() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Create `ViewBinder` to bind different type views with specific data beans. As you see, `provideViewHolder(View itemView)` corresponds for `onCreateViewHolder` in `RecyclerView`, and `bindView` corresponds for `onBindViewHolder` in `RecyclerView`.

```
public class ItemHeaderViewBinder extends ViewBinder<ItemHeader, ItemHeaderViewBinder.ViewHolder> {
    @Override
    public ViewHolder provideViewHolder(View itemView) {
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(StickyHeaderViewAdapter adapter, ViewHolder holder, int position, ItemHeader entity) {
        holder.tvPrefix.setText(entity.getPrefix());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemLayoutId(StickyHeaderViewAdapter adapter) {
        return R.layout.header;
    }
    static class ViewHolder extends ViewBinder.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvPrefix;
        public ViewHolder(View rootView) {
            super(rootView);
            this.tvPrefix = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_prefix);
        }
    }
}
```

Instantiate `StickyHeaderViewAdapter` for `RecyclerView` and register `ViewBinders` for each item types.

```
rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    List<DataBean> userList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new StickyHeaderViewAdapter(userList)
            .RegisterItemType(new UserItemViewBinder())
            .RegisterItemType(new ItemHeaderViewBinder());
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19304631)

Comment: @Rob Answer Fixed Thanks!

Comment: Bro, I want to set only the first position as header layout. Will this work?

Comment: @Andromeda sure that can be done ,you only specify in your Adapter,Please download a sample and Change the Adapter based on your data.

Answer (score 0):

For this lay out i suggest better option is use this header view 
https://github.com/edubarr/header-decor

Comment: In this library, is it possible to have the views in this manner like - header at top left and items surrounding it?

Comment: Okay, I'll try it and accept this answer if it works. Thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer